# I'm facing issues while running HelloWorld Struts program

Tags: java, struts

I've gone through all the steps of the tutorial given in this http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html example. Finally when i tried to run my program, I'm getting blank page with http://localhost:8080/StrutsExample1/helloWorld.do when I manually change the extension of the url to .jsp it only shows the html content, but its not showing the hello world message which we're setting dynamically.

What may be the problem?

Am I missing something.

Please help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us code. and web.xml

Comment: Please visit the url  http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html every thing is there, and I've not altered anything. So I did't pasted my code. Thanks for quick reply...

Comment: Check your logs, and what servlet container are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, the container parses the web.xml for the configurations and when it is done, it executes the welcome page which is your index.jsp
Look the url made formed is **http://localhost:8080/StrutsExample1/helloWorld.do**.
The parser has parsed till that and it has not mapped with the servlet "ActionMapping".
I think u have some problem in the directory structure u have formed.
Better do 1 thing, copy the whole project from vaanila.com and import to ur workspace, then see the structure formed...

Comment: Yes I've checked the code structure by importing the given war file. Its exactly the same file. but the funniest thing is the imported war file code is not running its giving 404 error.

Thanks for your reply...

Comment: for which file it is giving 404 not found..exception. Better once check the list of welcome file